# What is the difference between a 'fire door' and a 'burning door'?

Tags: meaning

I have a question about the English word “fire”.

Does *fire* have many meanings like flames or strong emotion, doesn’t it?

But, it does not have the meaning same as “fireproof “ or “fire-resistant”, right?

So why does the word “fire door” mean “fire-resistant door”?
When I read the word “fire door” for the first time, I thought that means “burning door”.

The same question can be said to the word “fire department “.
Is that burning department?
No, it’s the department for firefighters.

Firefighters is the word which mean the people who fight the fire!!
I can understand that well.

But, fire door…
I have no idea why it means fireproof door.

Comment: I remember when firemen started, tended and put out fires.

Comment: *Fire* does not mean *burning* in English; it means it has something to do with fire. For example, *firewood* is *wood* that you are planning to burn, not wood that is being burned. Similarly for *water*; if a piece of paper has a *watermark*, it's not necessarily wet, and a *waterwheel* is one that's turned by water, not one made of water (that's a *whirlpool* or a *maelstrom*). Possibly you are being confused by the meaning of *fire* in your first language.

Comment: In English we say we "dust the furniture", when we really mean "we remove dust from the furniture". It's very common, even in technical contexts where people often strive for precision in speech (e.g., your smartphone has a "jitter buffer" that is used to de-jitter signals). This is a similar case.

Comment: You may want to ask this on [ell.se] instead.

Comment: Attributive nouns have many types of semantic relationships to their head nouns. I've mislaid an article covering this, but over a dozen were mentioned. 'XY' here is 'Y is a passive guard against X" (fire door; fireguard) or 'Y is an establishment set up to counter X' (fire brigade/department), and we have 'Y is a base for a department set up to fight against X' (fire station) and 'Y is the leader of the personnel at a fire station' (fire chief) or '... a man trained to fight X' (fireman). Also, 'Y is a rehearsal of an evacuation procedure in case X occurs' (fire drill) comes to ...

Comment: mind. There are many others, for instance 'Y is an insect whose sting feels like a severe exposure to X' (fire ant). You can try _fire extinguisher_, _firepower_  and _firewater_ yourself. And a 'fire alarm' doesn't exactly fight a fire, but it is hopefully not passive.

Comment: A "fire door" could be a door that is to be used only in case of fire.

Comment: A fire door offers protection from fire, just as a raincoat offers protection from rain.

Comment: @GEdgar M-W lists an even narrower stipulative definition. And a totally different one, the door allowing fuel to be put into a furnace. But 'fire door' usually speaks of the construction, unlike 'fire exit'.

Comment: @PeterShor Meaning sometimes governed by collective peer pressure. Bradbury made that a butt of joke in his book, where firemen were those who burned books in future. Because accidental fires as such didn't exist, the old meaning of word became extinct. Or poor donkeys are now a swearword, because someone changed spelling of "ears" to "arse", and it got often missplelled as "ass" , intentional or otherwise.

Comment: A "fire door" is a door used to escape from a fire.

Comment: @Swift - _Or poor donkeys are now a swearword, because someone changed spelling of "ears" to "arse", and it got often missplelled as "ass" , intentional or otherwise._ Not quite.  'Ass' used to be the usual word for the animal, but people started using 'donkey' instead because it sounded too much like 'arse'.

Comment: @KateBunting not everywhere, different areas prefer old spelling. And I was somewhat facetios, didn't mention that "donkey" was an insult as well (something related to dung, its color, dung-like)

Comment: @Swift - 'Silly ass' was a common (and acceptable) colloquialism for a foolish person a century or so ago.

Comment: After those you can graduate to *fire sale.* Things get even harder for learners when the noun itself isn't literal: shoe tree, water noodle, saw horse.

Comment: @DjinTonic cat loaf!

Answer (score 5):

It's a very specific term.

Fire doors are fire-retardant, often heat insulating doors designed to prevent free airflow through the building thus they slow down fire spread. They should to be opened easily by a person with reduced ability to see or manipulate and are normally closed by design by means of springs or weights.

[image: Typical fire door]

By its nature, the term is describing a door, obviously, somehow related to a case of fire. Fire has got plural meaning, including an event where the building is on fire.

By origin, the term is an analog of firewall (otherwise known as brandmauer), but fire door can be used as a door in routine life unlike a firewall. Firewall functions as an erected obstacle in case of fire, literally a wall, while technically it's often a form of heavy door.

PS. Today we have another meaning of firewall and one time some software was using image of opened fire door as "exit" icon.

Comment: *Fire door* may be a term with a very specific meaning, but there is nothing special about the grammatical relationship between *fire* and *door* in the phrase *fire door*, which seems to be what the OP is unclear about - that's why the question belongs to the ELL site.

Comment: "Firewall" is a good example of a word which has the potential to have two, almost opposite, meanings. After all we talk of a bush fire as being "a wall of flame" so a "fire wall" could be a fire such as a bushfire. Similarly a "fireman" could be, up to a few decades ago, both a man who fought fires and one who tended the fire under the boiler of a steam-driven railway locomotive. Near parallels are "aircraft" which is not a craft made from air, "water channel" which is not a channel made from water and "petrol engine" which is a metal engine which uses petrol to run.

Comment: @BoldBen or fishman, which is a man who 1) cleans and prepares fish in food service or 2) who sells fish (a synonym to fishmonger). But it also sounds like some description of cross between human and fish , according to golden era comics tradition.

Comment: That's very true. That's particularly true of Batman who could be a superhero, a zoologist specialising in flying mammals or the personal attendant assigned to an army officer. Thinking too much about this sort of word in English is a route to total confusion!